# CART dropdown template changing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

Can I move 'Go to checkout' button and  cart subtotal to end of dropdown ?

Comment: I think it's possible. It would better if you post what you tried.

Comment: @Anime  where i can find phtml file of this dropdown ?